# Custom function in pandas does not print out values as expected

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have the following code:

```py
def fillRow(df, key, type_):
    print(f"Key (before if statements): {key}, Type: {type_}")
    if type_ == 0:
        replacement = df[key].median(skipna=True)
    elif type_ == 1:
        replacement = df[key].mean(skipna=True)
    elif type_ == 2:
        replacement = df[key].mode(dropna=True)
    print(f"Replacement: {replacement}, Key: {key}, Type of filling: {type_}")
    df[key] = df[key].fillna(replacement)
    return df
```

This function is meant to kind of "generalize" different types of replacement (just to save a little bit of time)

```py
short_qe = fillRow(short_eq, "Mag", 0)
for i in ["Mo", "Dy", "Latitude", "Longitude"]:
  short_eq = fillRow(short_eq, i, 2)
```

And this is an example of using it.

The output is following:

```
Key (before if statements): Mag, Type: 0<br>
Replacement: 6.5, Key: Mag, Type of filling: 0<br>
Key (before if statements): Mo, Type: 2<br>
Replacement: 0    11.0<br>
dtype: float64, Key: Mo, Type of filling: 2<br>
Key (before if statements): Dy, Type: 2<br>
Replacement: 0    25.0<br>
dtype: float64, Key: Dy, Type of filling: 2<br>
Key (before if statements): Latitude, Type: 2<br>
Replacement: 0    36.0<br>
1    38.0<br>
dtype: float64, Key: Latitude, Type of filling: 2<br>
Key (before if statements): Longitude, Type: 2<br>
Replacement: 0    36.1<br>
dtype: float64, Key: Longitude, Type of filling: 2<br>
```

Where the hell did "dtype" come from? What are those random numbers? Why does this work properly with "type 0" but not with "type 2"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your code, you are printing out [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) (which is what, for instance, the [mode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html) method always returns), which Pandas represents with the name of the original column and the data type of the value(s).

For instance:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 1, 9, 2], "col2": [8, 8, 7, 6]})

print(df["col1"].mode(dropna=True))
# Output
0    1
Name: col1, dtype: int64

print(f"{df['col1'].mode(dropna=True)}")
# Output
0    1
Name: col1, dtype: int64
```

One way to print only the values of the Series is to use the string representation provided by the [to_string](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) method:

```py
print(df["col1"].mode(dropna=True).to_string())
# Output
0    1

print(f"{df['col1'].mode(dropna=True).to_string()}")
# Output
0    1
```

So, modifying your code with `print(f'Replacement: {replacement.to_string()}, Key: {key}, Type of filling: {type_}')` should do the trick.